# How to reference objects in NSMutableSets

Tags: objective-c, struct, nsmutableset

I have a small C# library that I am trying to port (actually re-writing the C# code using it as a guide) to Obj-C.  The purpose of the library is to generate recurring appointments for an iOS calendar app.  I'm having problems porting C# structs to Obj-C objects.  This is what I have for one of the structs that holds the appointment info:

```
@interface Appointment : NSObject  {
@public
    NSDate *apptStartTime;
    NSDate *apptEndTime;
    NSString *key;
}
@end
```

One of the methods I wrote accepts a date, a set of schedules (also a port of a C# `struct`) and the appointment's list (I'm using a `NSMutableSet` which contains the Appointment interface above).  If I can get the appointments method working, I'm pretty sure I can figure out the remainder (I think).   This is the code that adds appointments to the `NSMutableSet`:

```
-(void) addAppointmentsForDate:(NSDate *)checkDate andSchedules: (NSMutableSet *)schedules andAppt:(NSMutableSet *)appointments {

Appointment *appt = [[Appointment alloc]init];

for(NSMutableSet *schedule in schedules)  {

    if(schedule.occursOnDate(checkDate))   {
        appt = [self generateAppointment:checkDate andSchedule: [schedules removeObject:schedules]];
        [appointments addObject: appt];

        }
    }
}


-(Appointment *) generateAppointment: (NSDate *) checkDate andSchedule: (Schedule *) schedule  {

Appointment *appt = [[Appointment alloc]init];

appt->apptStartTime = schedule->timeOfAppointment;
appt->apptEndTime = nil;  //  TODO  
appt->key = schedule->key;

return appt;

}
```

I'm getting build errors on the `if` statement:

> Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'Schedule *'

I have never used `NSMutableSets` before, nor have I tried to port from C# before.  I'm having a time with the port of the C# struct's, as you can see. I have read all of the Apple docs on sets, and several docs that explain the differences between C# and Obj-C.

Can somebody please either explain what I'm doing wrong, or point me to some good docs that can give me an example of referencing elements within sets?

Comment: Setting ivars directly through `->`?  Yeah, no;  don't do that.   Totally breaks encapsulation and is completely nonstandard out of a very narrow use case.

Comment: That's what the example of converting structs showed... so I followed it... it works, but if there is a better way, please show me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
@interface Appointment : NSObject  {
@public
    NSDate *apptStartTime;
    NSDate *apptEndTime;
    NSString *key;
}
@end
```

please please please write

```
@interface Appointment : NSObject
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSDate* startTime;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSDate* endTime;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSString* key;
@end
```

1. Don't make instance variables public. Instance variables should never, ever be accessed directly outside code belonging to that class.
2. Always start instance variables with an underscore character, like _startTime. That way any access to an instance variable stands out. (The code above will create instance variables for you).
3. Use accessors unless you have a very, very good reason not to.

Comment: Ahhh... makes perfect sense... and I don't think I'll have any problems accessing the properties this way...BTW, I normally @synthesize my properties because I don't like using the underscore... just personal preference.  anyway thank you... I'm gonna work on it tomorrow and I'll get back to you then.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I have the impression that you are not quite sure whether you are writing C++ or Objective-C code.

```
if(schedule.occursOnDate(checkDate))
```

How do you call an Objective-C method again?

```
for(NSMutableSet *schedule in schedules)
```

Are you sure about this? schedules is an NSMutableSet*. So you are saying that the elements of your schedules mutable set are again mutable sets? That is quite an unusual thing to have, but if you say so...

```
appt = [self generateAppointment:checkDate andSchedule: [schedules removeObject:schedules]];
```

This is more than weird. What do you think is

```
[schedules removeObject:schedules]
```

going to do? You expect a set to have itself as an element?

My advice: Go to bed. Have ten hours of sleep. After a good breakfast, have a look at your code again.

Comment: re the sleep... good idea... been too close to this for too long... and I do know better about calling Obj-C methods... caught up in trying to figure out what the C# code was doing and wasn't thinking...thank you for your time, I appreciate it.  SD